# How to find the most recurring word and print it in to a different text file in python?

Tags: python, text-files

So I have a text file (words.txt) that has words and their recurrence rate written next to them (example: paper, 4). I need to write a program that finds the most recurring words and print them into a different file. I wrote this program:

```
f = open("words.txt")
max = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    nr = int(line.split(",")[1])
    if(max < nr):
        max = nr
f.close()
f2 = open("doc.txt", "w")
f2.write(line.split(",")[0] + " " + str(nr))
f2.close()
```

I don't think its the correct way to solve this. Hope somebody could help.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a perfect job for [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You can just parse each word as a key and the number as the, well, count. Counter objects comes with the `most_common([n])` method which `return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least.`